# Has the ISS done any experiments on animals gestation such as mice? I particularly would like to know about embryo development in microgravity

Tags: iss, microgravity

Has the ISS done any experiments on animals gestation such as  mice?  I particularly would like to know about embryo development in microgravity

Comment: Space pup comes to mind: https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/893.html

Comment: Not posting this as an answer as I realize it's not *quite* what you're looking for - but they have [sent frozen mice embryos](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/station/research/experiments/1271.html) to the ISS and then seen how they develop upon return.